# datetime.now() - date.now() is returning -1 days

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

datetime is giving very spooky results:

In:

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
d1 = datetime.now(tz)

d2 = datetime.now(tz) + timedelta(seconds=0)

delta = d1-d2

print(delta, delta.seconds, delta.total_seconds(), sep="\n")
```

Out:

```
-1 day, 23:59:59.999930
86399
-7e-05
```

I have tried with and without timezones, with and without `timedelta(seconds = 0)` and have gotten the same result.

When I do:

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
d1 = datetime.now(tz)

d2 = d1 + timedelta(seconds=0)

delta = d1-d2

print(delta, delta.seconds, delta.total_seconds(), sep="\n")
```

I get 0 as expected. *What have I done?!*

I am importing as follows (if this could be the issue):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
```

I was reading the delta print out wrong, I didn't realize it was -1 day + 23:59. Oops..

Comment: That is pretty spooky

Comment: reverse the objects order: `d2-d1`

Comment: @Duckasaur: accept Jonathon's answer as the correct one and don't  try to answer by editing your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `datetime.now()` twice. Of course some amount of time passed between those two calls.

Your delta calculation is backwards. It should be:

```
delta = d2-d1
```